# Невозможно сериализовать ZonePoint т. к. он не имеет конструктора без параметров

Tags: c#

Есть список объектов, который нужно сериализировать, вылезает ошибка:

> Невозможно сериализовать ZonePoint т. к. он не имеет беспараметрического конструктора.

Проблема в том, что класс этот из подключаемой библиотеки и изменить его я не могу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделайте враппер над ZonePoint и во враппере управляйте сериализацией.

[OnSerializingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute.aspx)

[ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx)

Comment: Угу, вот пример для Version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18962224/276994